# One crank arm won't come off

Tags: crankset

First time taking the cranks off. The bolts, chinrings and drive side came out easy. Left is stuck. Should I open, pull or do something particular for it to come out?

[image]

Comment: If the first one came off without a puller it was probably too loose.

Comment: Sounds like you're using the wrong sized hammer.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You must use a Crank Arm Puller tool:

[Park Tools Crank Arm Puller](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B001VS1M20)

Here's how to use it:
[Video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BORfbbeo3gk)

Comment: I confirm this. Won't get it without a puller.

Comment: http://sheldonbrown.com/tooltips/cotterless.html is another good link as well. It shows using a different kind of crank puller.

Answer (score -2):

In addition to the answer provided by CQH, You could also get the crank off by putting the other crank back on (not very tightly), removing the bolt from the stuck crank, and riding a bit.

The crank should fall off after a little while, especially if you do bunnyhops and other things that put a lot of torque on the cranks.

This may not work with your octalink setup. I've only done it with square tapers.

This is a hack, and I wouldn't do it if you've got expensive cranks, but it's a good option if you don't have a crank puller.

Comment: Its a good way to mess up your cranks.

Comment: This method is only suitable when removing a [crank arm that is already headed to the scrap heap.](http://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/2184/how-to-remove-a-crank-arm-with-stripped-threads/2185#2185)

Comment: "This is a hack, and I wouldn't do it if you've got expensive cranks"